# Parse error in wordrpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

After seeking a solution about thumbnail size, I found in wordpress codex some codes and when i add them in editor in function php my blog stopped working. It is a blank page with this error message :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /home/taskylon/public_html/wp-content/themes/easel/functions.php on
>   line 487

I opened my cplesk profile but I cant see the specific line. I assume the problem is here:

```
if (!function_exists('easel_display_post_thumbnail')) {

    function easel_display_post_thumbnail($size = 'thumbnail') {
        global $post, $wp_query;
        if ($post->post_type == 'post') {

            $post_thumbnail = '';
            $link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'link', true );
            if (empty($link)) $link = get_permalink();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                if (is_home()) {

                    $post_thumbnail = '<div class="post-image"><center><a href="'.$link.'" rel="featured-image" title="Link to '.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size).'</a></center></div>'."\r\n";

                } else
                    $post_thumbnail = '<div class="post-image"><center>'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size).'</center></div>'."\r\n";
            } else {

                $url_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured-image', true);
                if (!empty($url_image)) $post_thumbnail = '<div class="post-image"><center><a href="'.$link.'" rel="featured-image"><img src="'.$url_image.'" title="'.get_the_title().'" alt="'.get_the_title().'"></a></center></div>'."\r\n";

            }
            echo apply_filters('easel_display_post_thumbnail', $post_thumbnail);
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me where exactly is the problem and how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: `</a></center></div>'."\r\n";` <<< `if (!empty($url_image))` use proper bracing for that

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean "use proper bracing "? Please, excuse my awareness... I'm totally unaware of all these!